# Why Google Colab thinks my file does not exist despite it being mounted from my Drive?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I made sure every single thing is correct with the related file names and their content addresses and so on yet I always get stuck upon executing the !sudo line command which should open and use a given file, it returns this error :

"Error: Cannot read file '/content/-p': No such file or directory"

As I have already said, the file does exist and is located in my Google Drive, I even copy pasted its specific path to make sure I put it right and yet the issue is still there, why? how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I just had similar problem.

In my notebook I first download zip-file from Github and then use geopandas read_file command to open that file. And although file was visible in file browser I got that Cannot read file -message.

But the problem was in path that I used when I downloaded file. I had the Github 'blob address', when I should have the raw-address. So the content of downloaded wasn't what I thought it was.